# Why isn't this 'for' loop valid?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

From C++ Primer 5th Edition by Lippman, page 182, consider:

```
int ia[3][4];
for (auto row : ia)
        for (auto col : row)
```

> The first `for` iterates through ia, whose elements are arrays of size 4.
>   **Because `row` is not a reference, when the compiler initializes `row` it will convert each array element (like any other object of array
>   type) to a pointer to that array’s first element.** As a result, in this
>   loop the type of `row` is `int*`.

I am not really sure that I understand how this auto works, but if I can assume it automatically gives a type to a row based on `ia` array members type, but I don't understand why this kind of `for`, where row is not a reference, is not valid. Why is this going to happen? *"pointer to that array’s first element"*, because of what?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The problem is that `row` is an `int *` and not a `int[4]` as one would expect because arrays decay to pointers and there is no automatic way to know how many elements a pointer points to.

To get around that problem `std::array` has been added where everything works as expected:

```
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 3> ia;
    for (auto &row : ia){
        for (auto &col : row){
            col = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `&` before `row` and `col` which indicate that you want a reference and not a copy of the rows and columns, otherwise setting `col` to 0 would have no effect on `ia`.

Comment: Note that the equivalent of `int[3][4]` is _not_ `std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 4>`, but `std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 3>`. This is a common mistake and worth pointing out, doubly so since you made it as well. ;-]

Comment: @Deduplicator what temporary copies ?

Comment: @Quentin: Ah, misread. He change the type *and* went for references. So no extra-copies. Still, the type-change is cumbersome, and is certainly API and perhaps also ABI-breaking, if calling other functions with that as an argument.

Comment: As an aside, traversing loops row major vs column major can have a significant performance implication for large-ish array sizes, so it is important to know what your rows vs columns really are.

Comment: Note, that you are now changing the values inside `ia`. The original code did not use references, implying that you work on copies and thus not propagates changes of `col` to `ia`.

Answer (score 38):

To prevent the decay of the `int[]` to `int*` you can use `&&`

```
int main() {
    int ia[3][4];
    for (auto && row : ia)
        for (auto && col : row)
            ;
}
```

Comment: Or just plain reference would be enough.

Comment: Actually, you should use rvalue references (`&&`) only in move constructors, move assignment operators or when plain references don't work and you exactly know what you are doing.

Comment: I used `&&` here specifically because that is what is being proposed in [N3853](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3853.htm) to support the even more reduced `( elem : collection )` syntax

Comment: @MichaelKarcher But that's not a (plain) rvalue reference - it's a [forwarding reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward).